# Reuse a command to pipe in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I use the following to indent the output of a configure script:

```
./configure | sed "s/^/    /"
```

Now I want to reuse the part behind the pipe, so I don't have to write

```
./configure | sed "s/^/    /"
make | sed "s/^/    /"
make install | sed "s/^/    /"
```

I've tried to put the `sed` in a variable like this:

```
indent=sed "s/^/    /"
```

and then do

```
./configure | indent
```

but that did not work - how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a BASH array to hold the sed command:

```
indent=(sed "s/^/    /")
```

Then use:

```
./configure | "${indent[@]}"
make | "${indent[@]}"
make install | "${indent[@]}"
```

OR else use a function for this sed command:

```
indent() { sed "s/^/    /"; }
```

Then use:

```
./configure | indent
make | indent
make install | indent
```

Comment: Right my preference is also for function, just wanted to show another way of doing it. But yes I should have placed function part above.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just make it an alias?

```
alias indent="sed 's/^/    /'"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(./configure; make; make install) | sed "s/^/    /"
```

Comment: +1. two comments: do it in the current shell using `{ list; }`; separate the commands with `&&` instead of `;` to short-circuit in case of failure.

Comment: I agree with you. Thank you for both hints.